# How do I get the x y co-ordinate of a selected point in a excel graph?

Tags: excel

Basically, I want to be able to copy the `x` co-ordinate and the `y` co-ordinate of a specific selected point in an Excel graph.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. When you hover you cursor over the point, you'll see a tool tip with the point values (`x` and `y`). If you want another kind of solution, you have to show the community what you have try so far, or else no one will help you... Consider reading <https://stackoverflow.com/tour>

Comment: No worries I figured it out.....
Adding a data label to that point helped.